# Show that the given function has an inverse and hence find its inverse.

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

> Show that the function $f(x) = (e^x - e^{-x})/(e^x + e^{-x})$ has an inverse function for all $x$. Hence find the inverse.

So, I don't know how to *show* the function has an inverse but if it does then I did this:

$x = (e^y - e^{-y})/(e^y + e^{-y})$

$x = (e^{2y} - 1)/(e^{2y} +1)$

$x (e^{2y} +1) = e^{2y} - 1$

$e^{2y}(1 - x) = (1 + x)$

:. $y = 0.5 ln(1+x) - 0.5ln(1-x)$

Now, how to show it has an inverse for all $x$ without literally showing it's inverse?

Comment: The function is $\tanh(x)$ and its inverse is $\tanh^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: I don't know hyperbolic functions.

Comment: You should check out this link: http://www.math.uaa.alaska.edu/~afmaf/classes/math252/notes/InverseHyperbolic.pdf

It talks about hyperbolic functions and their inverses.

Comment: you've already found the inverse so therefore the function has an inverse. (so I don't really understand what it is you're confused about)

Comment: Yeah but in a subjective question where it asks you to show that the function has an inverse, what do i write? @peek-a-boo

Comment: I don't know, it depends what your teacher expects etc. However, in general, finding the inverse of a function is much harder (sometimes impossible) compared to merely proving an inverse exists (atleast locally). You've done the harder second part of the question, so the first part has trivially been answered. My guess as to what the question may have intended is for you to calculate the derivative of the given function at every $x$, and show that it is non-zero. By the inverse function theorem, it will be invertible (atleast locally)

Comment: Take the derivative of the given function and argue that the derivative is nonzero. This guarantees the function is one to one, hence invertible.

Comment: Okay thanks, didn't know about that inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the function as $$\frac{e^x}{e^x+e^{-x}}-\frac{e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}=\frac{1}{1+e^{-2x}}-\frac{1}{1+e^{2x}}.$$

Differentiating then gives $$\frac{2e^{-2x}}{(1+e^{-2x})^2}+\frac{2e^{2x}}{(1+e^{2x})^2},$$ which is positive for all $x.$ Thus the function is increasing for all $x,$ hence it is monotonic, hence it is injective, hence it is invertible.